# Can't get FCKEditor to work in a virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, webforms, fckeditor

I have a WebForm that contains the following definition for the FCKeditor:

```
<FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor ID="txtBody" runat="server" 
            BasePath="/fckeditor/" 
            Height="480px"
            ToolbarSet="WebCal1"                
>
</FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor>
```

This works fine in my VS2008-based web application.  However, when I deploy it to a Virtual Directory in IIS, it looks for the FCKEditor files (e.g. javascript, stylesheets, etc...) in the `/fckeditor` folder, not in the `/MyVirtualDir/fkceditor`.

I've tried changing the BasePath to `~/fckeditor/`, but then it won't work on my dev machine.

What is the right way to go, so that the FCKEditor maps onto the right directory.  In my project the `fckeditor` directory is right off the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The piece that was confusing the FCKEditor was the SkinPath.  When I'd set the BasePath to "~/fckeditor/", it would path this string + the path of the skin to JavaScript (e.g. ~fckeditor/editor/skins/office2003).  And javascript could not resolve the relative path.

So the solution is to place this code in the form Page_Load event:

```
txtSignature.SkinPath = Path.Combine(this.ResolveUrl(txtSignature.BasePath), "editor/skins/office2003/");
```

Answer (score 1):

I user "~/fckeditor/" without a problem on both virtual directories, root directories and local machine.

Do you think something else could be going on? What does Firebug say is happening?